# Is there a way to only show/select certain dates on a calender/date time picker on visual basic express 2010

Tags: c#

I've been trying to create a rental car system and I'm struggling to find a way to limit what dates can be selected for renting a car.

This will be for putting in an access database using an sql which will store whatever dates are selected. I've tried using .blackout dates however didn't seem to work from my code and I have manages to set minimum and maximum dates which limit the dates able to be selected. However, I would like to be able to have various sets of dates and not just one which is set by the max min code.

```
    MonthCalendar1.MinDate = New DateTime(2019, 4, 2)
    MonthCalendar1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today

    MonthCalendar1.MinDate = New DateTime(2019, 4, 12)
    MonthCalendar1.MaxDate = New DateTime(2019, 4, 24)
```

The code I have rewrites instead of adding two max and min dates. There may be a better way of doing this therefore which I am not aware of.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you are asking.

Comment: Why are you using VB Express 2010 in 2019 if you are creating a new system?

Comment: Handle the `DataChanged` and `DateSelected` events and change the selection if it is invalid. Be careful not to block navigating to a new month, etc. when doing so. Optionally used bolded dates to indicate selectable or non-selectable dates.